# Websphere MQ classes needed in Websphere Application Server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, websphere, ibm-mq

So I have a JMS application deployed on a Webpshere Application Server, this application try to connect to the queue directy using a com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory and I wonder if I should include Websphere MQ jars in my application or should they be provided by Websphere Application Server. My application is currenty without them and I don't have a ClassNotFoundException but I do get issues (I have a SIB_MESSAGE error that appear), could this be related to the fact that my server is on PARENT_LAST or to an incompatibility between the WAS server version and the WMQ server version ?

Should I include Websphere MQ jars in my application ? Could this help with my issues or make it worse ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do **not** bundle WebSphere MQ jar files within your application. This will not be supported by IBM and is very bad practice.

You must use the WebSphere MQ classes for JMS that are shipped within WebSphere Application Server (which are included within the WebSphere MQ JCA resource adapter). This way, the version of the classes for JMS you use will be updated as and when you apply WebSphere Application Server maintenance.

Any version of the WebSphere MQ JCA resource adapter shipped within WebSphere Application Server can connect to any v7.x or v8 queue manager.

Without further details on the exact error you are receiving, I cannot help further.

Comment: What Pasty said.  Plus this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031560_.htm?lang=en

Comment: Thank you, I opened a thread on Websphere forum (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=416c520d-5acf-4737-bc58-31e3cfd2ee59) and ask my compagny experts about my issues but I wanted to be sure that I was doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth reviewing the scenario in the IBM Knowledge Centre that covers connecting the WebSphere Application Service to IBM MQ. [http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/prodconn_1.0.0/com.ibm.prodconn.doc/infocenter_homepage/mqwas_home.htm]

The reference to SIB suggests maybe the default messaging provider has been configured - whereas you wanted the MQ provider.